# Replace Column2 value with Dictionary Key Where Column1 Condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dictionary that relates the numeric label to the categorical label.

```
dict = {
0:'cat',
1:'dog', 
2:'fish
}
```

My dataframe(df) output looks like:

```
Feature  | Feature Value | Feature1 |  Feature1 Value

Pet        1               Thing       1
Person     Steve           Pet         1
Place      Texas           Place       Virginia
```

I want to replace the "1" with 'dog'.

I tried this.

```
df.replace({df.loc[df['Feature'] == 'Pet']: dict})
```

However, I know this is only looking at matching the Feature column, but not pulling in the value from Feature value to match in the dictionary.

What my dataframe(df) output should like is:

```
Feature  | Feature Value | Feature1 |  Feature1 Value

Pet        dog             Thing       1
Person     Steve           Pet         dog
Place      Texas           Place       Virginia
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your case, you can do like this:

```
df['Feature Value'].map(dict).fillna(df['Feature Value'])
```

This is Non-Exhaustive Mapping and `map()` function maps as per the label you have defined in your dictionary and fillna() helps to retain the existing values for non-matches. Also, `map()` is much faster than `repalce()`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace value based on Feature for individual sets of Features/Feature Values.

Note: Since the Feature_Value column is object type, I used as type(int) for the selected values.

```
df.loc[df['Feature'] == 'Pet', 'Feature_Value']= df.loc[df['Feature'] == 'Pet', 'Feature_Value'].astype(int).replace(d)

df.loc[df['Feature1'] == 'Pet', 'Feature1_Value']= df.loc[df['Feature1'] == 'Pet', 'Feature1_Value'].astype(int).replace(d)


    Feature Feature_Value   Feature1    Feature1_Value
0   Pet     dog             Thing       1
1   Person  Steve           Pet         dog
2   Place   Texas           Place       Virginia
```